# SOAP message without header - how to process?

Tags: soap

I've tried web search to find answer to my question but found only articles like how to create SOAP message without header.

In [wikipedia on SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP):

> SOAP header : A collection of one or more header blocks targeted at
>   each SOAP receiver. SOAP body : Contains the body of the message
>   intended for the SOAP receiver. The interpretation and processing of
>   SOAP body is defined by header blocks.

And:

> A SOAP message is an ordinary XML document containing the following
>   elements:
>   Element  -  Required
>   Header   -  No
>   Body     -  Yes
>   ...

How can be a message without header if processing of body is defined in header?

Comment: The SOAP header is optional. If a header is required, it is mainly mentioned in the WSDL file, that is bound to the webservice. The WSDL defines the functions of a webservice and the types, that are bound to the functions. It depends on how a function is defined. Some definitions need an action attribute in the soap header. Others are used by directly mentioning them in the SOAP Body. To keep it short: how a SOAP message should look like is more or less strictly defined in the webservice definition (wsdl).

Comment: @Marcel would you like to copy comment to answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SOAP header is optional. If a header is required, it is mainly mentioned in the WSDL file, that is bound to the webservice. The WSDL defines the functions of a webservice and the types, that are bound to the functions. It depends on how a function is defined. Some definitions need an action attribute in the soap header. Others are used by directly mentioning them in the SOAP Body. To keep it short: how a SOAP message should look like is more or less strictly defined in the webservice definition (wsdl).